# Home network, strange cable issue

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet, cat6

I'm encountering a strange issue when crimping connectors to my Cat6 cable. To save time I have done the same on a 1 m length to try and solve the issue I'm having with the cable routed through the house.

I have ordered the cable in the same order that the ends were on the 30 m cable I ordered, which is:

> W/O-O-WG-B-WB-G-WBr-Br

**586B**

[image: Cable Order]

My issue is that if I connect this cable to laptop and router A -> B works fine, I get perfect speeds based on speedtest.net. However, when swapping it around B -> A the laptop doesn't even detect a cable is connected.

I have plugged the cables into a tester in both configurations, so A -> B and B -> A and the tester shows the cable is crimped fine. Below are some images of my connections. I have tried multiple connectors too; could it be due to cheap connectors or something else?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Any chance you're using solid-conductor cables, but using 8P8C's designed for stranded cables? Or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wires and crimp done nicely.  Ditto on question - stranded vs solid ends?  That could be an issue.  Also, Cat5e or Cat6 certified ends.  There is a massive difference in quality, design, materials and style of ends.  I recently did a wifi upgrade with 60 Cat6 push-thru ends, no data issues, other that my crimp crosses from time to time.

Cat5e and Cat6 ends should still interoperate with little signal loss.  I lean toward the previous answers/options - solid/strand or the end device network card.

If your tests, of each wire pass, the cable seems fine, next option is the hardware at each end of the cable.

Comment: Issue appeared to be that the connectors I where using where titled Cat6, but they where very different to some others I got and quality sucked compared, works fine now with better connectors!

Comment: So answer other questions cable is stranded. So yeah hardware at the end of the cable was just poor or not Cat6 as titled.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful crimp, correct order for that standard. My only thoughts as to the cause:

- one of the wires is short, thus pins on RJ45 aren't piercing/touching wire making a connection. Whichever end the laptop DOESN'T work on look at that one. Sometimes you can see the wires looking at the top otherwise simply re-terminate
- If your cable tester can 'step' through each wire do that
- PC might be messed up, try another PC, or look at its network adapter 'negotiation' settings (if Windows in Device Manager)